# How do you say "to bond (with someone)" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, verbos

Me pregunto, ¿Cómo se dice "to bond (with someone)" en el español de tu país? He visto varias maneras de decirlo, pero todas mis fuentes dicen algo diferente.

Cuando digo "to bond (with someone)", lo que quiero decir es "ser y sentirse más cercano a alguien, digamos emocionalmente". Algunos ejemplos incluyen a miembros de una familia conociéndose y siendo más cercanos entre ellos, lo mismo que ocurre en una pareja.

Las formas que he visto incluyen:

- Hacer vínculos con alguien...
- Vincularse con alguien... (que pienso que no es lo correcto)
- Acercarse a alguien...

Nota: Agradezco cualquier corrección a mi gramática - solo te pido que me expliques la razón de aquellas correcciones, para así ir aprendiendo :)

Comment: *Algien* is not a Spanish word, the right spelling is *alguien*.

Comment: Congeniar con(get on/get along with)[entenderte con, caerle bien a, llevarte bien con, hacer buenas migas con, o como dice @Danielillo tratar de sintonizar con] donde hay reciprocidad o p.ej. estar más apegado a su familia, a su hijo, etc(become closer with)[nos hemos vuelto muy unidos, nos hemos convertido en buenos amigos] donde lo que hay es afecto, amistad o parentesco. Pasar el rato, salir(hanging out) sin crear el crear un lazo afectivo. En el caso de acercarse con el fin de(have been getting closer to get sth), etc. por interés u otra cosa.

Answer (score 2):

### Conectar

> Lograr una buena comunicación con alguien.

<sub>*Fuente: [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/conectar?m=form)*</sub>

### Sintonizar

> Dicho de una persona: Coincidir en pensamiento o en sentimientos con otra.

<sub>*Fuente: [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/sintonizar?m=form)*</sub>

---

Y sus derivados:

- Tener *conexión*
- Tener *sintonía*

##### Ejemplos

- Apenas conocerse *conectaron* inmediatamente.
- Tengo muy buena *sintonía* con mi jefe.

Por lo general *conectar* se utiliza para describir una situación sucedida en un momento determinado, mientras que *sintonizar* es intemporal o duradera en el tiempo.

- Juan y Luisa *conectaron* en la primera cita y aún mantienen una buena
  *sintonía*.
- *Sintonizo* muy bien con mi tío a pesar que al comienzo no teníamos una buena *conexión*.

Comment: We have connect in English. To bond is not to connect. sintonizar is to be on the same wavelength.

Answer (score 2):

> to bond with someone

es conectar/vincular (se) emocionalmente con alguien

Siendo que el término requiere cierta correspondencia o reciprocidad, (no basta con empatizar solamente —lo que es posible de manera unilateral— sino algo más activo) Para involucrarse en cualquier tipo de relación es un pre-requisito "congeniar", "pegar onda", "sintonizar con" y establecer "formar un vínculo".

Creo que, dado ese presupuesto de simpatía recíproca, para acercarse más íntimamente a otro, lo más cercano que se me ocurre en este momento para sugerir una expresión equivalente a `bond with someone` es

> "estrechar lazos" con alguien

La definición de [estrechar](https://dle.rae.es/estrechar?m=form) tiene una acepción de `Hacer más íntima la amistad, intensificar la unión o el cariño entre personas.`

Answer (score 1):

Dos opciones más que no se han dado:

> ***intimar*** intr. Pasar a tener una amistad íntima.

> ***entrañar*** prnl. Unirse, estrecharse íntimamente, de todo corazón, con alguien.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que la palabra que buscas en *"Español"* para "bond" es "unido/a", - "unir con", ya que puede servir tanto para un amigo, una pareja como alguien más cercano en la familia.

Algunos ejemplos;

Me siento muy "unida" a mi Madre.
Me siento muy "unida" a mi amigo Pedro.
Me siento muy "unido" a mi pareja.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda. Saludos.

Diego M.